# Are there any benefits in storing arrays inside of a function vs inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Are there any benefits at all to storing arrays inside of a function vs storing arrays inside objects?  The values stored in these arrays will not change, but there could be thousands of lookups.  I am wondering if I should switch to objects now.

```
function arrayFunc (arr) {
    if(arr=='one'){
       return [99,2,3,4,5,6,7,98,9,341,82,36,44,5,55,6,3,66,77,45,241,144,1,334];
    }
    else if(arr=='two'){
       return [83,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,5,55,6,3,726,77,125,241,144,1,65];
    }
    else if(arr=='three'){
       return [64,2,56,95,5,544,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,5,55,6,3,66,77,45,241,144,1,2];
    }
 };

 var x=arrayFunc('two')[index];
```

By object I mean something like this

```
var arrayObj = {
  one:[99,2,3,4,5,6,7,98,9,341,82,36,44],
  two: [83,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33],
  three: [64,2,56,95,5,544,7,8,9,11,22]
};
```

Comment: inside object being    var arrays = {
 one: [4,5,6,7,98,9,341,82,36,44,5,55,6,3,66,77,45,241,144,1,334],
 two: [83,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,5],
 three: [5,55,6,3,66,77,45,241,144,1,2]};

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code: it is much easier to read there.

Comment: Didnt mean to post that.  Accidentally hit return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two major improvements: performance and code legibility.

Performance: You will not be recreating the array every time, and with hashed keys you will not be checking equality on every key.

Code legibility: This is the standard way to hold data because it is easier to read. Follow the convention.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the array will be re-created every time you call the function. This is a significant overhead if you are basically indexing into the array once.

It is not entirely clear to me what you mean by *store in object vs. function*, but if by that you mean that the arrays are owned by an object that is repeatedly used and not recreated every time, then yes, the object way will be preferred.